# How to put the correct intent parameters?

Tags: java, android-intent, arcore, sceneform

I tried to make a SceneView intent where a 3d-model can be viewed.

```
   Intent sceneViewerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    sceneViewerIntent.setData(Uri.parse("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/KhronosGroup/glTF-Sample-Models/master/2.0/Avocado/glTF/Avocado.gltf"));
    sceneViewerIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.googlequicksearchbox");
    sceneViewerIntent.putExtra("mode","3d_only");
    mContext.startActivity(sceneViewerIntent);
```

When this intent opens, it gives the user an option to view the model in your own environment, but I want to turn this off and according to https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/scene-viewer#3d-or-ar you should be able to pass on a parameter called 'mode' which can have the value '3d_only' which should prevent the user from being able to view the model in AR.

I tried to pass on this value by means of `sceneViewerIntent.putExtra("mode","3d_only");` but it doesn't work. Am I passing on the information correctly?

Answer (score 0):

You're not sending any information anywhere. "3d_only" should be some variable, otherwise you're not sending anything. Also, you have to retrieve your code on the other end by doing String string = getIntent().getStringExtra("mode");

Comment: But since the intent is an Action View and it uses a package, I don't have access to this other end of the code right?

Comment: Add the rest of your code so I can have a look at it and see what your "mode" actually is.

Comment: This is all the code. The 'mode' comes from https://developers.google.com/ar/develop/java/scene-viewer#supported_intent_parameters Under supported intent parameters, they list the intent parameter 'mode' that can have the values '3d_only', 'ar_only', 'ar_preferred' and '3d_preferred'